# Configure Kafka consumer with EJB? Is it possible to configure mdb for Kafka with EJB?

Tags: apache-kafka, ejb, kafka-consumer-api

I want to replace existing JMS message consumer in EJB with Apache Kafka message consumer. I am not able to figure out the option to configure Apache Kafka consumer with EJB configuration.

Comment: Are you using Spring for your runtime library, or something else?

Comment: This question is extremely generic and requires a lot of reading by author. Kafka is not an easy drop-in replacement.

Answer (score 0):

Kafka is not a straight messaging solution (comparable to say RabbitMQ), but can be used as one.

You will need to translate your JMS concepts (topics, queues) into Kafka topics (which are closer to JMS topics).

Also given that consumers have a configureable/storeable start offset you will need to define these policies for your consumers.